# Can a function be fastcall & inline in linux kernel?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I would like to define a function that will be invoked from entry_32.S. It will be invoked just before the real system call handling function is called.

In order to avoid the overhead of function calling and parameter passing, can I declare my_foo as

```
   fastcall inline int my_foo (int n);

    /*in entry_32.S*/
    pushl %eax
    CFI_ADJUST_CFA_OFFSET 4
    SAVE_ALL
    ....
/* My code begins*/
    call my_foo
    cmpl $0, %eax
    jne syscall_wrong
    movl PT_ORIG_EAX(%esp), %eax
/* My code ends */
    call *sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
```

Comment: My guess is that the syntax is correct. But the "inline" modifier has no effect, because the assembler is not so smart that it can replace the existing "call my_foo" line with the code of my_foo.

Comment: inline is always a hint the compiler doesn't have to listen because at the end of the day the compiler knows best :P Most likely it will be inlined but there's a chance it may not be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler can inline functions in C code (whether they have the `inline` keyword or not) but the assembler is not that smart.  What you write in assembly is exactly what will be assembled, no optimization (like inlining) at all.